# free youtube API Key to use with android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I'm building android application to list videos from youtube, I've read the API documentation and created developer account on google.
I'm trying to get the API but it require me to have an android certificate account,
why do I need this, even I want to list videos without any modification, why it does not need that account for IOS developers, it is just click the generate API and done. ??
is there is any free API key for testing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can register for a key on the Developer Console for free, considering you have a google account.

Go to the Google Developers Console.
Select a project.
In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the YouTube Data API v3.
In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials.
The API supports two types of credentials. Create whichever credentials are appropriate for your project:

1. OAuth 2.0: Your application must send an OAuth 2.0 token with any request that accesses private user data. Your application sends a client ID and, possibly, a client secret to obtain a token. You can generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for web applications, service accounts, or installed applications.
   Learn more
2. API keys: A request that does not provide an OAuth 2.0 token must send an API key. The key identifies your project and provides API access, quota, and reports.

If the key type you need does not already exist, create an API key by selecting Create New Key and then selecting the appropriate key type. Then enter the additional data required for that key type.

From : https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register